# Find all the sequences of elements that occurred more than N times in a list of nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists of lists, `x`, and its first two sublists are shown as below

```
x[0] = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
     ['e', 'f', 'g', 'a'],
     ['d', 'c', 'f'],
     ['e', 'g'],
    ]

x[1] = [['a', 'b'],
     ['a', 'f', 'g', 'k'],
     ['e', 'd', 'f'],
    ]
```

I want to find all the sequences of elements that appeared in consecutive sub-sub-lists and overall in `x` at least N times. In this case it would be: `['a', 'f', 'f'], ['b', 'f', 'f'], ['a', 'f', 'd'], ['b', 'f', 'd'], ['a', 'a', 'd']` if I want 3-consecutive elements with `N=2` occurrences.

If I also want 2-consecutive elements with `N=2` occurrences then it would add `['a', 'f'], ['b', 'f'], ['f', 'f'], ['f', 'd'], ['a', 'a'], ['a', 'g'], ['b', 'g'], ['b', 'a'], ['g', 'f'], ['a', 'd'], ['f', 'e']` to the final output.

Is there any efficient way to achieve this and generalise to the whole `x` with more than 100k sublists? Thanks.

Comment: The question makes no sense. Give a solid sets of inputs and outputs. It's not clear at all how you get from A to B.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you take x[0] and x[1] you'd have a list of 2 sublists with each consist of its own sublists. I do apologise if it wasn't clear. I want to discover sequences of entries that occurred N times in x. And by a sequence of entries, e.g. ['a', 'f', 'f'] appeared in x[0][0]->x[0][1]->x[1][2] as well as in x[1], making N=2.

Comment: Still not clear. Does this relate to the example data at the top? I don't see the array `['a', 'f', 'f']` anywhere in there.

Comment: Indeed. E.g. in `x[0]`, 'a' is in x[0][0] -> 'f' is in x[0][1] -> 'f' is in x[0][2], thus making ['a', 'f', 'f'] a sequence of 3 elements. This sequence appeared again in x[1]: x[1][0][0]->x[1][1][0]->x[1][2][-1].

Comment: Probably consecutive is not the right word to use here.. going by your logic, how does ["a", "f", "d"] and ["b", "f", "d"] become consecutive?

Comment: Could you clarify your requirements? E.g., I don't understand why `['a', 'a', 'd']` isn't part of the results of the first example or why `['a', 'd']` isn't part of the results of the second example.

Comment: @Timus Aha! You're right! It was my mistake, I have added them both now to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @ Arun Kaliraja Baskaran Yeah, I guess by "consecutive" I meant for example 'a' is in x[0][0] -> 'f' is in x[0][1] -> 'f' is in x[0][2] and thus `['a', 'f', 'f']` in 3 consecutive sublists of x[0]. I went back and forth many times when I was writing the question to refine the wording, guess it was still confusing to many alas!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused (I like the problem, though): You can find `['d', 'e']` twice in `x[0]` (starting in `x[0][0]` and starting in `x[0][2]`. And `['f', 'e']` occurs in `x[0]` and `x[1]`. Are there additional rules that exclude them from the results?

Comment: You're right, these two would be part of the output as well. No additional rules. I will edit the question again now. One can think of these as Ngrams but the grams are across consecutive sublists so one analogy is x[0]...x[n] each is a doc and for each doc there are a list of paragraphs and the aim is to find words that appear in consecutive paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still a bit unclear about the exact rules but here's an idea which might be a starting point:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product, chain

def count_seqs(lol, n):
    return Counter(chain(*(
               product(*lol[i:i + n]) for i in range(len(lol) - n + 1)
           )))

count_all = sum((count_seqs(lol, 3) for lol in x), Counter([]))
N = 2
result = {seq for seq, count in count_all.items() if count >= N}
```

But: (1) I'm unsure if that produces the results you're looking for, and (2) I don't know how that does performance-wise.

**EDIT**:
For inspection of the sequences in `x`:

```
def seqs(x, n):
    return [
        sum((list(product(*lol[i:i + n])) for i in range(len(lol) - n + 1)), [])
        for lol in x
    ]

print(seqs(x, 3))
```

**EDIT 2**: Technical speed increase via multiprocessing:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product, chain
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import perf_counter  # Only for timing

# As before - change if necessary
def count_seqs(lol, n):
    return Counter(chain(*(
               product(*lol[i:i + n]) for i in range(len(lol) - n + 1)
           )))

# Function for summing over counts of a piece of x (a "chunk")
def count_chunk(x, n):
    return sum((count_seqs(lol, n) for lol in x), Counter([]))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = 4  # Length of the sequences

    start = perf_counter()  # Only for timing
    count_all = count_chunk(x, n)  # Essentially the "classic" way
    end = perf_counter()  # Only for timing
    print('Classic:', end - start)  # Only for timing

    start = perf_counter()  # Only for timing
    k = 500  # Size of a "chunk"
    with Pool() as p:  # Multiprocessing using Pool and starmap
        # Counting over the chunks in several processes
        counts = p.starmap(count_chunk,
                           ((x[i:i+k], n) for i in range(0, len(x), k)))
    count_all = sum(counts, Counter([]))  # Aggregating over the chunk counts
    end = perf_counter()  # Only for timing
    print('Multiprocessing:', end - start)  # Only for timing
```

I ran that with the following sample `x`

```
import random

elements = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
x = [[list(random.sample(elements, random.randint(2, 10)))
      for _ in range(random.randint(5, 50))]
     for _ in range(10_000)]
```

and got as results

```
Classic: 2755.06
Multiprocessing: 733.94
```

Better, but not very encouraging for a `x` of length 100,000 ...

Comment: Many thanks for this @Timus. It seems to miss a lot of instances or it's doing the summation wrong. For example, with `count_seqs(lol, 5)` it returns more seqs than with `count_seqs(lol, 3)` and the same `N`, which in theory doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Blue482 Hm, I haven't found an inconsistency with smaller samples (yet). I think intuition about the numbers can be deceiving here - which includes me :)) I have added a function that makes inspecting the sequences a bit more easy. Maybe it's helpful. I'll sleep over it, maybe I'll find a flaw tomorrow.

Comment: After some testing, I think the issue being when there are duplicate items in a sub-sub-list, then the function outputs the inflated number of sequences. I think it'd e ok if I do `sum((count_seqs(lol, K) for lol in [[list(set(x)) for x in xlist] for xlist in X]), Counter([]))` instead.

Comment: @Blue482 I did start with a version that collected _all_ sequences in a `lol` (list of lists) in set to avoid duplicates (a bit more "global" than your version), but then started to wonder if that is what you need. Really depends on what the "correct output" should entail. Minor point: I think you don't need the `list` call in your new version - `[[set(x) for x in xlist]` should be okay.

Comment: Thanks very much @Timus! Is there any way possible this can be made more efficient at all? I have a `x` the size of 100k and each `x[i]` has between a few and hundreds of sublists. It's taking forever atm..

Comment: @Blue482 Tough question. I don't really have a good answer. You can speed it up technically via multiprocessing (I've added some sample code to the answer). But that's probably not good enough. The only way I see beyond that would be to exploit additional structure in the data - if there is any. Without additional structure the problem offers not much to trim it down. (At least I don't see a way.)